# How to avoid server call during JavaScript Iframe Print

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am printing the content of an iframe with JavaScript. Following is a snippet.

```
var myFrame = window.frames[IFRAME_NAME];
myFrame.focus();
myFrame.print();
```

But when the 3rd line executes, it opens a print dialog of the browser. Everything works fine until I press the print button of the print dialog. **The moment I press the print button it makes a server call of the current url and logout the session**. How to avoid server call during printing of iframe ?

Comment: Have you tried something like $("#Iframe").load(function(e) {});

Comment: But why I will call a function after iframe load. I don't understand the logic. Please explain how to call print after iframe load.

Comment: After reading the question I understand that you want to call the print function once the contents of the Iframe has loaded. Kindly correct me if I am wrong. So if this is the case you should do all things in the (iframe).load() method. Just like we do things in Jquery ready().

Comment: How is the above code called? Is it from an `<A>` tag and do you `return false;`?

Comment: Actually the content of the iframe is populated through JavaScript by document.write function.